# Get value of select onChange in Functional Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a select in a functional component and I cannot get the value when I select an option.
I could only find solution for a class based component. I thought useState would do the trick but I am missing something...

```
const ClientChoice = (props) => {
    const [selectedClient,setSelectedClient] = useState([]);

    function handleSelectChange(event) {
        setSelectedClient(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <select onChange={handleSelectChange}>
            <option value="one">One</option>
            <option value="two">Two</option>
            <option value="three">Three</option>
        </select>
    )
}
```

The target is `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for FC: add value to your select

```
const ClientChoice = (props) => {
    const [selectedClient,setSelectedClient] = useState([]);

    function handleSelectChange(event) {
        setSelectedClient(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <select value={selectedClient} onChange={handleSelectChange}> //set value here
            <option value="one">One</option>
            <option value="two">Two</option>
            <option value="three">Three</option>
        </select>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not providing the value to `select` and change default value for `selectedClient`:

```
   const ClientChoice = (props) => {
        const [selectedClient,setSelectedClient] = useState("one"); //default value
    
        function handleSelectChange(event) {
            setSelectedClient(event.target.value);
        }
    
        return (
            <select value={selectedClient} onChange={handleSelectChange}> //set value here
                <option value="one">One</option>
                <option value="two">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
            </select>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Ok so now the change is detected. However if I console log my `selectedClient` before and after my `setSelectedClient(event.target.value);` I see the same value...

Comment: this is due the `asynchronous` behavior of `setState` , if you want to see the change in state then see this:  https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-brahmagupta-f6i1n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In your code you don't have that issue. The value changes immediately...

Comment: because i have used `useEffect` hook, which tracks the value of `selectedClient` , it only triggers when the `selectedClient` value changes

Comment: Thanks ! How can I pass the new value to my parent ? I have a component which contains my `ClientChoice` and other components with data based on that choice...

Comment: Just pass your `state` as a `props` i.e. `<ClientChoice selectedClient={selectedClient}/>`